# Write python polars lazy_frame to csv gzip archive after collect()

Tags: python, gzip, lazy-evaluation, python-polars

What is the best way to write a gzip archive csv in python polars?

This is my current implementation:

```
import polars as pl
import gzip

# create a dataframe
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "foo": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "bar": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "ham": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
})

# collect dataframe to memory and write to gzip file
file_path = 'compressed_dataframe.gz'
with gzip.open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    df.collect().write_csv(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below is a further test of the gzip method. Polars will recommend passing a path for better performance instead a file object. While gzip write is very costly at a 60s, gz read was only 4 seconds compared to 0.89 s for the regular csv.

```
import polars as pl
import gzip
from datetime import datetime
import os

import numpy as np

# Create a large dataframe with 10 million rows and 5 columns
rows = 10000000
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "col1": np.random.randint(0, 100, rows),
    "col2": np.random.randn(rows),
    "col3": np.random.choice(["apple", "banana", "orange"], rows),
    "col4": np.random.randint(0, 100, rows),
    "col5": np.random.randn(rows)
}).lazy()

# collect dataframe to memory and write to gzip file
file_path = 'compressed_dataframe.gz'
comparison = 'comparison.csv'

start = datetime.now()
df.collect().write_csv(comparison)
print(f"comparison saved at {datetime.now()-start}")

start = datetime.now()
pl.read_csv(comparison)
print(f"comparison read at {datetime.now()-start}")

start = datetime.now()
with gzip.open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
    df.collect().write_csv(f)
print(f"gz saved at {datetime.now()-start}")

start = datetime.now()
with gzip.open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    print(pl.read_csv(f))
print(f"gz read at {datetime.now()-start}")


print(f"{comparison} has size of {os.path.getsize(comparison)}")

print(f"{file_path} has size of {os.path.getsize(file_path)}")
```

Output:

```
comparison saved at 0:00:01.505098  comparison read at 0:00:00.899469
gz saved at 0:00:57.891954  Polars found a filename. Ensure you pass a
path to the file instead of a python file object when possible for best performance.shape: (10000000, 5) 
gz read at 0:00:04.539318 
comparison.csv has size of 517290342 
compressed_dataframe.gz has size of 224153795
```

compression ratio is 2.30

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're applying `collect()` to a `pl.DataFrame`, which does not have a `collect()`. If you're working with a `pl.LazyFrame` you can apply `collect()` to it.

The implementation you're using to write to a gzip file is the standard way of doing it in python, and works well!